# MYSQL syntax multiple counts and tables in one query

Tags: mysql, syntax, count

I'm trying to get syntax right to do multiple counts on multiple tables with joins.

Tables:

follow_table

```
id|follower_id|followed_id
```

Photos

```
id|photoname|userid
```

Here is starting point (with thanks to ypercube):

```
   SELECT f1.followed_id
          , p.*                     
          , COUNT(*) AS followers       
     FROM follow_table AS f1
     JOIN follow_table AS f2
       ON f2.followed_id = f1.followed_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(p.*) AS numphotos
             FROM `photos` p
            GROUP BY p.userid) p2 
       ON p2.userid = f1.followed_id
    WHERE f2.follower_id = $userid          
    GROUP BY f1.followed_id;
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' COUNT(*) AS followers FROM follow_table AS f1 JOIN follow_table AS ' at line 2

Comment: Wrap it in another select and count sub selected data.

Comment: not sure what you mean.  How would I do that?  Thanks

Comment: please post an example input and an expected output

Comment: sql error is You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' COUNT(*) AS followers FROM follow_table AS f1 JOIN follow_table AS ' at line 2.  It runs if I take out LEFT JOIN but then I don't get number of photos